# Why does my NSMutableArray initWithContentsOfFile return Null?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a problem with a NSMutableArray.

When I Log this code:

```
cityObject = [citiesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"%@", cityObject.cityName);
```

It Logs:

```
2014-09-15 11:12:55.599 JSONStoryboard[1865:707465] London
2014-09-15 11:12:55.605 JSONStoryboard[1865:707465] Bombay
2014-09-15 11:12:55.609 JSONStoryboard[1865:707465] Kuala Lumpur
2014-09-15 11:12:55.612 JSONStoryboard[1865:707465] New York
2014-09-15 11:12:55.615 JSONStoryboard[1865:707465] Berlin
2014-09-15 11:12:55.618 JSONStoryboard[1865:707465] Duesseldorf
```

But when I try to use `initWithContentsOfFile` here, it doesn't Log what I expected it to:

```
self.namesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:cityObject.cityName];
NSLog(@"%@", self.namesArray);
```

The result of it is:

```
2014-09-15 11:16:26.241 JSONStoryboard[1875:708269] (null)
2014-09-15 11:16:26.247 JSONStoryboard[1875:708269] (null)
2014-09-15 11:16:26.250 JSONStoryboard[1875:708269] (null)
2014-09-15 11:16:26.253 JSONStoryboard[1875:708269] (null)
2014-09-15 11:16:26.256 JSONStoryboard[1875:708269] (null)
2014-09-15 11:16:26.259 JSONStoryboard[1875:708269] (null)
```

When I expected it to Log my cities names.

What is the problem here? How can I add my cities names into namesArray?

Answer (score 0):

It looks unlikely that you have files at the path "London", "Bombay" etc. because these are not even valid paths. Therefore initWithContentsOfFile will return nil.

Find out where the files are actually stored and created a path to each file. For example

```
NSString* myDataDirectory = [self whereIStoreAllTheFiles];
NSString* cityPath = [myDataDirectory stringByAddingPathComponent:@"London"];
NSArray* cityData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:cityPath];
```

Code is not tested in any way.

Comment: The cities "London", "Bombay", etc. are different strings saved on a url, I save them into a string, in this case called "citiesArray", then I read each city name on a tableViewCell using the: "cityObject = [citiesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];". Displaying them one by one on the cells, the thing is that I want to save the cityObject.cityName on a new array called namesArray. How can I do this?